# How to store and retrieve UISegmentedControl in plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios-simulator, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to store segmented control into the property list and also retrieve from plist too.
So how should I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a UISegmentControl Outlet in your viewcontroller

```
IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *mySegment;
```

Connect it to your UISegmentControl in Interface Builder

Add this IBAction method and wire it up in Interface Builder

```
- (IBAction) changeSegment: (id) sender {
    //save UISegment value in NSUserDefaults
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:[sender selectedSegmentIndex] forKey:@"savedSegment"];
}
```

Restore the saved value when the view is loaded in viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.mySegment.selectedSegmentIndex = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"savedSegment"];
}
```

Comment: How could we make an switch statement or an if statement for a segment (using NSUserDefault)?